# How can I restore the default status bar color?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

In one of my activities, I don't want the status bar to have any color. I want it to stay in whichever color the is before my app is ran.

I can change it to black, but black isn't the default, the default is kind of transparent. I don't want tot try to find which transparency is the correct one because It might be different on other people's phones so I want to basically not use the color feature of the status bar in this particular activiy

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      Window window = getWindow();
      window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
      window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLACK);
 }
```

Comment: Isn't default is black on Lollipop. If you don't set `colorPrimaryDark` in your theme you will get default color automatically.

Answer (score 7):

By default title bar is colored using `colorPrimaryDark` (docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html), see pic below). Or when you look at Material theme:

```
<item name="statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

You should also see this posts

- https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

[image]