# How to restore default navigation bar color in Android?

Tags: java, android

I set navigation bar color in my app like this:

```
getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat
                        .getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.my_color));
```

and after change fragment I want to reset navigation bar color(come back to default). How do this ? I want not set in my style
android:navigationBarColor">@color/my_navigaton_bar_color< and when I want set default, call:

```
 getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(ContextCompat
                        .getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.my_navigaton_bar_color));
```

P.S. I was try save in variable getWindow().getNavigationBarColor() but it always -1 , a also try decode value from android.R.attrs.navigationBarColor but it also doesn't work

Comment: You have to set the color again, but you could use the primaryColor or colorAccent of your app that usually is where the color is from

Answer (score 2):

This can be done inside **styles.xml** using

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/theme_color</item>
```

or

```
window.setNavigationBarColor(@ColorInt int color)
```

This image may also help you to indentify which color goes where [image]

You can find details: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978320/5382685)

Comment: I see this details but on some device i have white and on some black navigationbar

Comment: Have you tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348336/how-to-change-system-navigation-bar-color/54861794)?